# Iphone application Blow into mic to put in standby mode

Tags: iphone, microphone, standby

I am building a simple application to blow into the iPhones microphone, and have it then put the iphone in sleep mode how would I go about starting an application like that if I already have the UI built? Like how would I detect a mic blow, at any time while the application is running  in the background, and then have it go into standby mode?

Comment: Have a read of this article about background aware apps on iOS 4 and above: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1646438 But I don't think it will be possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do that. While you can detect "blow" you wont be able to put iOS device to stand by mode with official API

Comment: But in the timer/clock app that comes with the iPhone you can select an option that says "when timer finish sleep iPod" and you can choose for it to go back into the lock screen when the timer finishes. Is this just apples privileges that allow it to be done?